# Find $H'(x)$ if $H(x)=\int_{3}^{x^2} (\sin t)^3 dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

> let $H(x)=\int_{3}^{x^2} (\sin t)^3 dt$. Find $H'(x)$.

I understand that this question is related to the fundamental theorem of calculus, but how should I approach it?

Comment: It is a little hard to read your integrand, however you should understand my answer.

Comment: @gbox I reformatted the equation; did I do it right?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang edited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that by the fundamental theorem of calculus we have that if
$$f(x)=\int_a^xg(t)dt$$
Then
$$f'(x)=g(x)$$
So here we just have to apply the chain rule because if
$$f(x)=\int_a^{h(x)}g(t)dt$$
Then
$$f'(x)=g(h(x))h'(x)$$
So your answer is
$$H'(x)=2x\sin^3(x^2)$$

Comment: Why do we help the chain rule?

Comment: Let $$f(x)=\int_3^x\sin^3(t)dt$$ then we have that $H(x)=f(x^2)$ hence we use the chain rule.

Comment: Did that answer your question? @gbox